# Defining custom variables on Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run a command like below on "Execute shell" section,

```
./test.sh --model Toyota --year 2000
```

So I want define variables on the pipeline config page and use this variables on the command above like this;

```
./test.sh --model $car --year $year
```

There should be a "car" and "year" dropdown menu or a textbox on the pipeline page and when user selects any car or year, these selection will be used in the command above.

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add a `parameters` directive at the `pipeline` scope:

```
parameters {
  string(name: 'car',
    description: 'The car name.')
  string(name: 'year',
    description: 'The car year.')
}
```

and then access within the `params` object:

```
./test.sh --model $params.car --year $params.year
```

Comment: Should I add this one to Jenkinsfile? Not sure is there any much difference but I'm using "Freestyle project", not "Pipeline".